# How to create pagination with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I want to create pagination in a search bar in CodeIgniter, but I don't get actual pagination.

**Controller code:**

```
public function compatabilty(){

  $this->load->model('user_model');
  $this->load->model('admin_model');
  $data['result'] = $this->user_model->get_compatibility();
  $this->load->view('compatabilty',$data);

}
public function compatabilty_search()
 {
   $submit = $this->input->post('searchcompatible');
    if(isset($submit)){
     $new = $this->input->post('search_text');
     $datas['result'] =$this->admin_model->fetch_data($new);
     $this->load->view('compatabilty_search',$datas);
    }   
 }
```

**Model:**

```
 function fetch_data($new)
 {
   $this->db->select("*");
   $this->db->from("au_compatible_products");
    if($new != '')
    {
     $this->db->like('Device', $new);
    }
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->result();
  }
```

**View:**

```
  <div class="search-result" >          
    <ul><font>Serch Results for</font>
    <?php  foreach ($result as $key ) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $key->Model_Number;?> </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you looked into this: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html , You don't need to create the pagination. Codeigniter already the providing pagination library.

Comment: Check [here](https://www.guru99.com/codeigniter-pagination.html)

Comment: "but I don't get actual pagination": what is the name of your model? Is it possible you have just a typo, as you use sometimes use "compatible" and sometimes "compatable"?

Comment: "but I don't get actual pagination": what is the name of your model? Is it possible you have just a typo, as you use sometimes use "compatible" and sometimes "compatable"?  Admin_model.php

Comment: Have you looked into this: codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html , You don't need to create the pagination. Codeigniter already the providing pagination library. – I don't understand that how i do because i want it in search result.

Comment: Check here - its work for static not in search